# How can I get this small program to run in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
class Main { 
private static int foo(int a) { 
int b = a + 6; return b; 
} 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
int c = 5; int x = foo(c); 
System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

I want to know how to run the code above without changing anything (except minor errors). I've already tried creating a new class.

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon `;` after `System.out.println(x)`

Comment: *Step 1:* Create a Java Project in Eclipse. *Step 2:* Create a Java class named `Main`. *Step 3:* Change the content of the created file to what you show here. *Step 4:* Fix the compilation errors. *Step 5:* Save and run the code.

Comment: Please use backticks rather than single-quotes in order to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a project.
*File > New > Java Project*

Complete the setup, and then go to *File > New > Class*

Paste your *fixed*  (check below) code and run.

```
    private static int foo (int a) {
        int b = a + 6;
        return b;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                int c = 5;
                int x = foo(c);
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I tried doing that, yet there are still errors that show up.

Comment: Your output should be 11. I runned this myself and it worked fine. Please paste your errors. EDIT: I edited my code with a try-catch block so it would be easier for you to detect the error, however as I mentioned, it works just fine with me...